# Benchmarked bioacoustic dataset

Tags: benchmarks

Which publicly available terrestrial bioacoustics dataset (avian ~0-15 kHz) has been most commonly used to benchmark model-based (any functional estimator probabilistic or machine/deep learning) audio classification accuracy (or other metrics derived from a contingency table such as precision, recall, etc...)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome @MattWeldy could you add a bit to your question to narrow the scope a but? Are you looking for a specific radon? In air or underwater?

Comment: Thanks for the question @MattWeldy but it needs more detail to be on this forum. Explain specifically what you mean e.g. what benchmarks - speed/recall/precision? Model-based - do you mean deep learning/machine learning - explain these terms which may be obvious to you but not to everyone on the forum. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps look at Stowell et al (2019) "Automatic acoustic detection of birds through deep learning: The first Bird Audio Detection challenge" Methods in Ecology & Evolution https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1111/2041-210X.13103

From the Abstract:

3. Multiple methods were able to attain performance of around 88% area under the receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve (AUC), much higher performance than previous general-purpose methods.
4. With modern machine learning, including deep learning, general-purpose acoustic bird detection can achieve very high retrieval rates in remote monitoring data, with no manual recalibration, and no pretraining of the detector for the target species or the acoustic conditions in the target environment."

---

The paper discusses four datasets used in the challenge, and according to the data accessibility statement two of them are available, quote:

Both audio and annotations are available under CC-BY-4.0 licences:

warblrb10kaudio: https://archive.org/details/warblrb10k_public

ff1010bird audio: https://archive.org/details/ff1010bird

Annotations: https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.3851466.v1.

---

Stowell et al (2019) has also been [cited 190 times according to Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=50270686932665232&as_sdt=5), so I'm sure there are other leads to follow there too.